# Summarise data between given value of a categorical variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking for a clever and fast way to summarise data in a data frame. The data and desired output looks as follows:

```
categoriesVector <- c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B")
propertyVector <- 1:length(categoriesVector)
dataVector <- 100 * rev(propertyVector)
df <- data.frame(categoriesVector, propertyVector, dataVector, stringsAsFactors = F)
df

desiredData <- c(700, sum(500, 400, 300), 100)
desiredProperty1 <- c(3, 5, 9)
desiredProperty2 <- c(3, 7, 9)
desiredDF <- data.frame(desiredData, desiredProperty1, desiredProperty2)
desiredDF
```

Basically I need to sum `data` and keep first and last `property` between each two occurrences of `Category A`. After a lot of headbanging I found a clumsy solution, which I am looking to find an improvement on in terms of clarity and performance, preferably with `dplyr`:

```
numRows <- dim(df)[1]
.groupedID <- rep(NA, numRows)
ID <- 1
.groupedID[[1]] <- ifelse(df$categoriesVector[[1]] == "A", 0, ID)
for(i in 2:numRows)
{
  if(df$categoriesVector[i] == "B")
  {
    .groupedID[i] <- ID
    if(df$categoriesVector[i - 1] == "B")
    {
      .groupedID[i] <- .groupedID[i - 1]
    }
    ID <- ID + 1
  } else
  {
    .groupedID[i] <- 0
  }
}

tempDF <- 
  df %>% 
  mutate(ID = .groupedID) %>% 
  filter(ID != 0) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(desiredProperty1 = head(propertyVector, 1),
           desiredProperty2 = tail(propertyVector, 1),
           desiredData = sum(dataVector)) %>% 
  select(desiredData, desiredProperty1, desiredProperty2)
tempDF
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `cumsum()` to make your groupings and then process based on those like this:

```
df %>% mutate(Agroups = cumsum(categoriesVector == "A")) %>%
    filter(categoriesVector == "B") %>%
    group_by(Agroups) %>%
    summarise(propertyStart = min(propertyVector),
              propertyEnd = max(propertyVector),
              dataTotal = sum(dataVector))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Agroups propertyStart propertyEnd dataTotal
    <int>         <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>
1       2             3           3       700
2       3             5           7      1200
3       4             9           9       100
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I'd do with `data.table`. First create `spanNumber` variable to identify each span of "B" surrounded by "A", then calculate the variables you specified:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, catShiftConcat := paste0(categoriesVector, shift(categoriesVector, fill = "A"))]
df[categoriesVector == "B", spanNumber := cumsum(catShiftConcat == "BA")]
df[!is.na(spanNumber) , .(desiredData = sum(dataVector), 
     desiredProperty1 = propertyVector[1], 
     desiredProperty2 = propertyVector[.N]), by = spanNumber]
##    spanNumber desiredData desiredProperty1 desiredProperty2
## 1:          1         700                3                3
## 2:          2        1200                5                7
## 3:          3         100                9                9
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative `data.table` method that uses `rleid` to group runs of the categories vector is

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(categoriesVector,
              desiredData=sum(dataVector),
              desiredProperty1=propertyVector[1],
              desiredProperty2=propertyVector[.N]),
          by=rleid(categoriesVector)
          ][categoriesVector == "B",][, c("rleid", "categoriesVector") := NULL][]
```

The contents in the first `[]` return the desired output and are calculated aggregated to runs of the categories vector. The second chain subsets the observations by keeping those for which the categories vector is B. The third `[]` removes two helper variables, and the final `[]` is just there to print the result to screen.

This returns

```
   desiredData desiredProperty1 desiredProperty2
1:         700                3                3
2:        1200                5                7
3:        1200                5                7
4:        1200                5                7
5:         100                9                9
```